# javascript slide animation without a framework

Tags: javascript, animation

How would you do a javascript slide type animation without using a javascript framework like jquery?

It would have to be cross browser also.

Could I cherry pick this functionality from jquery's source?

Comment: Is there an example of what you had in mind by "slide-type animation?" do you mean like PowerPoint slide animation? Or rather animation that slides things around?

Comment: You could *look* at jQuery's source to see how they do it. Chances are you'll reinvent most of jQuery before you reach your goal.

Answer (score 2):

[Javascript Sliding Panels using Generic Animation](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-sliding-panels-using-generic-animation)

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your link, but I don't see any animations in Chrome

Comment: These are examples. Click on the dark blue to see the animations for each examples.